# How to setup Apache mod_rewrite to redirect all but one subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, webserver, apache

I've just created a new website and am ready to switch from an my current webserver to a new webserver.

The current webserver will be renamed www2
The new webserver will be known as www

I want to redirect all traffic from www2 to www *except* for one directory.  My directory structure looks like this:

```
 /var
     /www
         /html
            index.html
            page2.html
            /orange
                 index.html
            ...
            /archive
                 index.html
                 important-page1.html
                 important-page2.html
            /turquoise
                 index.html
            ...
```

I would like to redirect everything to the equivalent www page

```
 e.g. www2.mydomain.com/orange/index.html -> www.mydomain.com/orange/index.html
 www2.mydomain.com/turquoise/index.html -> www.mydomain.com/turquoise/index.html
```

**EXCEPT** for the /archive folder.  I would like users requesting :

www2.mydomain.com/archive/important-page1.html to view the page on www2 and **not** be redirected.

Do I use mod_rewrite or mod_redirect?  And can I set this up in httpd.conf?

Thanks

Comment: **>>Do I use mod_rewrite or mod_redirect?** Depends on whether you want to redirect or just rewrite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would need mod_rewrite.
Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^archive
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: The 301 in `R=301` is a [permanent redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx), you'll need to change it to 302 if you want it to be temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `VirtualHost` config in httpd.conf (or `httpd.conf.d` file) for www2.mydomain.com add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/archive.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com$1
```