# redirect subdomains bar one

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain

So I've set up a **Amazon EC2** and registerd a few domains with **123-reg**, i've set up my Apache VirtualHost  But now I'm going to need to set up a few sub domains (like ***kitten***.example.com). But it's only going to be a few, and I would like the rest of the subdomain wild cards to go to the base like this:

**kitten**.example.com  -> **kitten**.example.com 
**BUT**
*.example.com -> example.com

currently my DNS with **123-reg** is as follows:

```
www         A       198.168.0.0
         
kitten      A       198.168.0.0

*           A       198.168.0.0
```

and my Apache **httpd.conf** is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  <Directory "/var/www/example.com">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/kitten.example.com"
  ServerName kitten.example.com
  ServerAlias kitten.example.com
  <Directory "/var/www/kitten.example.com">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

so how do i redirect all those wildecard subdomains to my base domain?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to map `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` to your base domain directory. 
or if you wish to change the domain name also, then write a .htaccess rule for it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual host directive that doesn't specify the ServerName or ServerAlias.  This will catch all virtual hosts on that IP address (you specifcy all IP's on port 80) that do not map to any other virtual host specification.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot /www/default
      ...
  </VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#default

However, if you want to send a 301 HTTP Header (permanently redirected), you'll need to use mod_rewrite or something similar:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

[How to setup Apache mod_rewrite to redirect all but one subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034489/how-to-setup-apache-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-all-but-one-subfolder) is one good example .. needs to be modified to suit your needs if the first option isn't sufficient for your needs.